# Erro: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type X but this dictionary requires a model item of type Y

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Está dando erro ao iniciar a consulta e na geração da lista com os resultados:

Erro:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Int32,BlogWeb.Models.Abastecimento],<>f__AnonymousType1`3[System.Int32,System.Int32,System.Decimal]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[BlogWeb.Models.Abastecimento]'.

Abastecimento Controller:

```
public ActionResult AbastecimentoResumo()
{
    //código irrelevante

    var resultado = consulta.GroupBy(c => c.NumCarro.NCarro)
                            .Select(gp => new
                                         {
                                             NumCarroId = gp.Key,
                                             LitroTotal = gp.Sum(c => c.Litro),
                                             TotalConsumido = gp.Sum(c => c.TotalGasto)
                                          });            

    // código irrelevante

    return View(resultado);        
}
```

A minha *view*:

```
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model IList<BlogWeb.Models.Abastecimento>

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Relatório de Vendas";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"; }

<table id="customers">
    <tr>
        <th>N° Carro </th>
        <th>Quant. </th>
        <th>Valor Unitário </th>
    </tr>
    @{ 
        foreach (var a in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @a.NumCarro.NCarro </td>
                <td> @a.Litro</td>
                <td> @a.TotalGasto</td>
            </tr>
        }
    }
</table>
```

ModelAbastecimento:

```
public class Abastecimento
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set;}
    [Required]
    public virtual int Litro { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? DtAbastecido { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal VlrUnit { get; set; }
    public virtual int Km { get; set; }
    public virtual decimal TotalGasto { get; set; }
    public virtual int Km_Andado { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Autor { get; set; }
    public virtual Compra NomeProduto { get; set; }
    public virtual Veiculo NumCarro { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Jovem, note a minha edição na sua pergunta, este é o código relevante para que ela possa se respondida. É tudo que precisamos para reproduzir o problema.

Comment: Agora, tente editar a pergunta e colocar o código de classe `BlogWeb.Models.Abastecimento`, por favor.

Comment: @LINQ desculpa, é que pensei que poderia ser algo acima que podia interferir, as coisas a cima, peço desculpas

Comment: Não precisa pedir desculpas, só tou tentando te instruir

Comment: muder .Select(gp => new  .... para  .Select(gp => new Abastecimento

Comment: @MarconcilioSouza Onde está a propriedade `LitroTotal` no tipo `Abastecimento`? E as propriedades `NumCarroId` e `TotalConsumido`?

Comment: @LINQ ... na realidade ele esta criando um tipo Anonymous com nomes diferente do que realmente deveria ser ... na classe tipada.  a view espera Abastecimento e ele passar um Anonymous ...

Comment: Isso, eu sei bem. A pergunta que eu te fiz foi outra. Como mudar o tipo do `Select` para o mesmo que o da _view_ vai resolver o problema? Só vai causar mais problema.

Comment: @LINQ, nossa não sabia disso... desculpa ai .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja, o erro diz que **os tipos não são os mesmos**.

Tudo que você precisa fazer agora é com que eles fiquem de acordo

Crie uma nova classe, eu vou chamá-la de `ViewModel` porque não consigo identificar o padrão de nomenclatura que você está usando

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int NumCarroId { get; set; }
    public int LitroTotal { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalConsumido { get; set; }
}
```

Na *view*, mude a segunda linha para

```
@model IList<SeuNamespaceAqui.ViewModel>
```

E dentro da table, você vai ter que usar os campos de `ViewModel` obviamente

```
foreach (var a in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td> @a.NumCarroId  </td>
        <td> @a.LitroTotal </td>
        <td> @a.TotalConsumido </td>
    </tr>
}
```

E no método `GroupBy`, troque `Select(gp => new { })` para `Select(gp => new ViewModel { })`

Comment: Se eu de vez colocasse `LitroTotal`, `TotalConsumido` colocasse as mesma nomenclaturas, não teria problema e outra duvida é que normalmente eu uso viewModel pra fazer acesso entre o Controller e View, não tem problema chama ele, até tem AbastecimentoModel que é as classes ViewModel?

Comment: se precisa que eu poste o meu AbastecimentoModel(ViewModel) pra ajuda-lo

Comment: Teria problema, o tipo tem que ser exatamente o mesmo, ter os mesmos nomes não adianta. O que você está fazendo é justamente passar informações do controller pra view, não existe problema nisso.

Comment: Mas o tipos são mesmo tipos, Dois int's e um decimal

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam Isso não quer dizer nada, eles tem que ser exatamente o mesmo.

Comment: E outra coisa a meu parametro `ConsultaResumo` faz consulta do abastecimento, não tem problema?

Comment: LINQ não tem como continuar isso na segunda, meu expediente acabou e sou proibido de fazer horas extras

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam Sim, deixe um comentário aqui na segunda-feira

Comment: Bom dia LINQ, poderiamos continuar com a ajuda, em questão do codigo?

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam Sim, qual é o problema?

Comment: Era sobre o erro em questão de não ser o mesmo tipo, quando havia o requerimento da lista

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam Ok, isto está respondido na minha resposta.

Comment: É que eu estou com algumas duvidas ainda, é que eu tenho classes de viewmodel, onde são as classes que eu utilizo para interagir com ações da view e que seria mesmo necessario cria a classe nova ou poderia utiliza essa?

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam Você tem alguma classe que tem exatamente os mesmos campos desta nova?

Comment: Com esses nomes não, mas o mesmo tipo de variável sim

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72716/discussion-between-linq-and-guilherme-padovam).

Comment: @GuilhermePadovam Eu estou com um pouco pressa, podes entrar no chat?